# Can anyone give me a complete example of JMS Asynchronous implementation in Mule?

Tags: asynchronous, jms, mule

I've been searching a lot and yes, I saw a few implementations but I still don't get how a client can consume those responses asynchronously, can anyone explain me or give me an example, please?

The only thing I got in mind now is, a little flow that sends the request using one-way exchange-pattern to specify that it will be asynchronous. Great, then what? I mean, once it's in the queue. How me, as a client, can get my messages after a certain amount of time? The correlationID takes place here, as far as I know, and maybe correlationGroups, but how do I implement this? I couldn't understand it well yet.

This is the code I made for testing async messaging, now that delivers the message to the queue, and stays there... now, it needs to be consumed somehow from the very same client when he desires to. How can I achieve that?

```xml
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" specification="1.1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="false" doc:name="Active MQ">
    <reconnect frequency="5000"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>
<flow name="jms-amq-async-producerFlow1" doc:name="jms-amq-async-producerFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8081" path="asyncjms" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#['setting a new payload ']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="AsyncQueueTest" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true"/>
</flow>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the client expect a synchronous response, use the `request-response` exchange pattern.

Comment: Yes but i got a few scenarios where the client isn't expecting a response when the time he sends the request. Going to post the little piece of code i made for the async impl.

Comment: To consume on demand, use `muleClient.request('jms://AsyncQueueTest?connector=Active_MQ', aTimeOut)`

Comment: Yeah, works great by using the client.request Thanks!! :) now i need to know if i want to get an specific message from the queue and not the last one. Just pick up one, maybe by adding filters? is it possible to do it from java?

Comment: You should be able to use a selector parameter in `request`, in the URI.

Comment: yeah, i thought so, something like selector="messageId" or filter="messageId" or whatever. Something to investigate :) thanks David, you are awesome! Post the response bellow so i can check it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To consume on demand, use:

```
muleClient.request('jms://AsyncQueueTest?connector=Active_MQ', aTimeOut)
```

You should be able to pass a JMS selector as an extra query param, like: `&selector=JMSMessageId%3D12456`

Comment: Is it bad to use "&messageRootId=<ID>" instead of the JMSMessageID?

Comment: Nope, if you're sure there's such a property on the JMS Message.

Comment: Yep, great :) using the messageRootId i get the message, but maybe was an incorrect usage for it